# How to detect pitch abnormalities in audio stream?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I need to extract audio stream from a video and check whether it has any pitch changes or abnormalities. Ideally, we want to quantify any pitch changes in the audio stream. I'm aware that I can use ffmpeg to extract the audio stream from the video. However, what tools or programs (python?) can then be used to identify and quantify any pitch changes or abnormalities in the audio stream?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Pitch analysis is not an easy task, luckily there are existing solutions for that. https://pypi.org/project/crepe/ is an example that looks promising.

You could read the resulting CSV of pitch data into a Pandas dataframe and perform whatever data analysis you can think of.

For example for the pitch change analysis you could do

```
df['pitch_change'] = df.frequency.diff(periods=1)
```

To get a column representing the pitch change of every time unit.